# python: convert a list of 1/0s to a list of boolean

Tags: python

Trying to convert a list of 1/0s to a list of boolean.

`bool([1,0,1,0])` doesn't seem to work.
`[1,0,1,0] == 1` doesn't work.

Is there another way (hopefully non-list comprehension)?

Comment: this seems like an X Y problem, is there something that you are actually trying to solve since you could use 1 and 0 as a boolean and it will still work...

Comment: Why do you not want to use a list comprehension?

Comment: For posterity: Speed comparisons between the various answers for [Python 3.5.2](https://repl.it/F5K7/2) & [Python 2.7.10](https://repl.it/F5K4/1), sorted by performance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In python 2

```
 bool_list = map(bool,int_list)
```

In python 3:

```
 bool_list = list(map(bool,int_list))
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that `map` doesn't return a list in python 3.

Answer (score 8):

```
[x==1 for x in list]
```

is a general approach that you can easily adapt should you ever have a list with entries other than `0` or `1`.

Comment: This is by far the fastest way of the three already posted: .31 sec vs .54 sec for `map()` and .60 for `bool()` according to timeit

Comment: @TemporalWolf I'm not convinced.

Comment: @Mitch Then run timeit yourself. Even the generalized `timeit.timeit("[not x==0 for x in lst]", "lst = [1, 0, 1, 0]")` runs in half the time of the `bool()` version (which will convert all ints to bools).

Comment: It may be faster, but it says in the question "hopefully non-list comprehension". (Either way it probably is an XY problem)

Comment: @TemporalWolf I did (with `%timeit`), and Mithilesh's answer runs slightly (though negligibly) faster on inputs of all sizes. Python 3.5.2. Or possibly Thomas' is faster on _very_ small inputs. In any case, not convinced that this answer is "by far the fastest of the three posted".

Comment: @Mitch Ah, Python 2.7 it's different. In fact, the fastest I've seen on 2.7 is `[not not x for x in lst]", "lst = [1, 0, 1, 0]` which I assume benefits from bypassing the function call to `bool`.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Hm yeah, that's interesting.

Comment: @Mitch I think I figured it out: [Python 3.5 fixed](https://repl.it/F5K7/1) That comparison was unfair because it didn't return a list. it looks like `x==1` takes the cake in both versions, although to be fair, performance is rarely the top priority. Readability is usually better, which would for me be `bool()`, then `map()`, then a direct comparison.

Comment: @TemporalWolf You did, yup `not not` still looks like a nice ugly speed hack :)

Answer (score 6):

The solution using `numpy` module:

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([1,0,1,0])
print((l > 0).tolist())
```

The output:

```
[True, False, True, False]
```

---

`l > 0` - each element of the array `l` is tested, if it's bigger than `0`. The results of these tests are the *Boolean* elements of the result array

---

This approach is also quite good when dealing with multidimensional arrays:

```
l = np.array([[1,0,1,0], [1,1,1,1], [0,0,1,0]])
print((l > 0).tolist())
```

The output:

```
[[True, False, True, False], [True, True, True, True], [False, False, True, False]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, using list comprehensions:

```
lst = [1, 0, 1, 0]
[bool(x) for x in lst]
=> [True, False, True, False]
```

Answer (score 2):

In terms of readability, `bool()` and `map()` are better options. In terms of speed, they are about half as fast:

For Python 3.5.2 ([repl.it](https://repl.it/F5K7/2)):

`[not not x for x in lst]`

is faster than the other three options, although only slightly faster than

`[x==1 for x in lst]`

For Python 2.7.10 ([repl.it](https://repl.it/F5K4/1)):

`x==1` edges out `not not`, but both are still twice as fast as the other two.

---

`not not` also has the advantage over `x==1` in that it will apply to all values, not just `0` and `1`