# How to convert number 1 to a Boolean in python

Tags: python, boolean

I have seen similar questions asked, but none have answered my question. I am relatively new to python, and have no idea what i'm doing.

Comment: Unless you don't want to explicitly use Boolean type variable you don't need to. Python accepts it as True in many expression.

Comment: `bool(1)` returns `True`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: convert a list of 1/0s to a list of boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010942/python-convert-a-list-of-1-0s-to-a-list-of-boolean)

Answer (score 53):

Use:

```
>>> bool(1)
True
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> int(bool(1))
1
>>> int(bool(0))
0
```

Can convert back too.

Or a clever hack that could be quicker would be:

```
>>> not not 1
True
>>> not not 0
False
>>>
```

Converting back:

```
>>> int(not not 1)
1
>>> int(not not 0)
0
>>>
```

Answer (score 9):

Only the following values will return False when passed as a parameter to `bool()`

- None
- False
- Zero of any numeric type. For example, 0, 0.0, 0j
- Empty sequence. For example, (), [], ''.
- Empty mapping. For example, {}
- objects of Classes which has **bool**() or **len()** method which returns 0 or False

Everything else returns True

[Source1](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-bool.html)
[Source2](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/bool)

Answer (score 4):

Unless you don't want to explicitly use `Boolean` type variable you don't need to. Python accepts it as `True` in many expression:

```
print(True == 1)
print(False == 0)
```

**Out:**

```
True
True
```

In other cases you can use bool(1) of course.

```
print(bool(1))
print(bool(0))
```

**Out:**

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 3):

Very simple:

```
bool(1)
```

Here are a few scenarios, to show:

```
print(bool(1))
```

Will return: True

```
print(bool(0))
```

Will return: False

Comment: Nitpick: `bool(1)` returns `True`, `print(bool(1))` *prints* "True"

Answer (score 1):

To convert `1` to boolean type:

```
print(bool(1))
```

Which returns `True`.