# Python to Booleans table

Tags: python-3.x

I need to convert hex value for 0xc437
To binary like  1100010000110111 and this binary associated with True false
For example here
['True','True','False','False' ,'False' and so on
And if the value 0x0000, I want to show all False

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert hex to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1425493/6045800) and [python: convert a list of 1/0s to a list of boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42010942/6045800)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest might be string formatting:

```
x = 0xc437
[bool(int(c)) for c in f"{x:016b}"]
# [True, True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, True, True]

x = 0x0000
[bool(int(c)) for c in f"{x:016b}"]
# [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

`f"{x:016b}"` gets you the binary representation of `x` padded with leading zeroes to length 16.